# Getting mac 308 error roughly every 4 times I build simulator any ideas?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios-simulator, simulator

I'm building my app and seeing a black screen when it's built and then when I quit the simulator it indicates I'm running into mac error 308. I have to close simulator and rebuild my app which has been annoying. Has anyone run into this issue and found the solution? I'm currently using mac M1 and latest software (MacOS Ventura 13.2, iOS 16.2)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a beta version of xcode?

Also, I've had this problem before due to a corrupted asset file I've put into my project, double check your assets perhaps.